# Matlab print does not keep background transparency

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am creating surface plots with a transparent figure background in Matlab R2015b. Consider the code

```
n=49; 
h=figure;
[x,y]=meshgrid(1:n,1:n);
surf(x,y,peaks(n),'EdgeColor','none')
set(h,'Color','none')
set(h, 'InvertHardCopy', 'off');
print(h,'-dpdf','peaks.pdf')
```

which gives me a pdf file `peaks.pdf` where the axes background is white, but the figure background transparent.
However, if I set `n=1000`, the background is no longer transparent, but black (as the figure is displayed in Matlab).
Does anyone know, what the issue is, and how to prevent this? Thanks!

Comment: Probably related to OpenGL rendering. See [https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/24434-opengl-and-print](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/24434-opengl-and-print). And other related google search results.

Answer (score 1):

The key is the property `set(h, 'InvertHardCopy', 'off');`

From the MATLAB help:

> InvertHardcopy — Figure background color when printing or saving
>   'on'(default) | 'off'
>    Figure background color when saving or printing,
>   specified as one of these values:
>
> 'on' — Change the figure background and axes background colors to
>   white. 
>   'off' — Use the same colors as the colors on the display. To
>   change the figure background color on the display, use the Color
>   property of the figure. To change the axes background color, use the
>   Color property of the axes.

Accordingly, you should use `set(h, 'InvertHardCopy', 'on');` to get the desired pdf output.

Comment: Setting `InvertHardCopy` to `on` would change the background colour to white, as you stated, but I am interested in having a transparent background for the figure instead. So I actually need to set it to `off`.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. I think setting the renderer with `print(h,'-painters','-dpdf','peaks.pdf')` will produce the output with transparent background. At least it did the trick on my system (Win7, MATLAB R2016a) with `n=100`. However, setting `n=1000` will be really slow with this renderer. I just interrupted the script after approx. 90 minutes....